# How to reduce the SSH failed login attempts because of authentication?

Tags: ssh

I want to reduce the number of attempts to login into an SSH client from an SSH server to be 2-3. How do I change this is the config file of the server?
this is in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try using [Fail2Ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) to reduce the number of attempts.  It is in the repositories, so it can be installed simply with `sudo apt install fail2ban`.  Then the link has documentation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The per-connection value is configured using `MaxAuthTries` configuration option:

> **MaxAuthTries**
>
> Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted per connection.  Once the number of failures reaches half this value, additional failures are logged.  The default is 6.

To set lower, add `MaxAuthTries 3` to your `sshd_config`.